# iOS NSAllocateMemoryPages failed raised by -[NSData dataWithBytes: length:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, crash, heap-memory

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** NSAllocateMemoryPages(10969344) failed'
```

I have been seeing this exception several time, but it's not reproducible.
From crash report, I know it crashed after -[NSData dataWithBytes:] this line.
I searched for answer but I couldn't find one 100% convincing to me.

1. Could that be caused by trying to alloc memory and exceed heap memory limit?
2. If yes, how to solve it other than optimizing overall application memory management?
3. If no, what couldn't cause this crash?

Thank!!

Comment: The actual method signature seems to be `-[NSData dataWithBytes:length:]`. I wonder what are your actual arguments when the crash happens?  Either way, the ~10MB you are asking from `NSAllocateMemoryPages()` doesn't look like too much...

Comment: @ni
        CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 720, 1278, 8, 720 * 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 720, 1278), image.CGImage);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:CGBitmapContextGetData(contextRef) length:720 * 1278 * 4];

Comment: Mmh... Although `CGBitmapContextGetData()` returns a `void *`, the **Swift** docs list an `UnsafeMutablepointer?`. I wonder what happens in your code if `CGBitmapContextGetData()` fails and returns `NULL`? Not sure that might be the casue, though... Just guessing.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thanks for replying! Above is the code I was having exception with. Yes, I think 10mb of data alloc shouldn't be a problem, but it just happened. Actually, it was like happening once out of >10000 times of code executions. So, it wouldn't be surprise that my code was not buggy but the device was experiencing high memory stress... But I still want to figure out if my code was come thing I should optimize. Thanks!!

Comment: @JayceeJiang As you mention, allocations like this can fail when the device is in a low-memory situation — this exception gets thrown whenever a large allocation fails in this way (when `NSAllocateMemoryPages` is used). There's not much you can do in this case but potentially catch the exception and display an error message to your user.